# Can't open system settings in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gnome-control-center

I'm getting this error when I try to start system settings (in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) from command line using `gnome-control-center -v`:

```
(gnome-control-center:19769): user-accounts-cc-panel-ERROR **: 16:58:37.061: failed to read pwquality configuration: local_users_only
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it wroks now, not sure how it fixed itself but all I did was:

1. sudo gnome-control-center

- it did show some window but all empty

2. gnome-control-center display

- this opened a window with display settings - all okay

3. Out of a sudden, now I can run just: gnome-control-center or click settings icon and it works fine, magic!